# Generating a call graph with Clang

Tags: parsing, clang, call-graph

How do I use clang to generate a call graph of C++ code? I understand I need to use [this](http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/CallGraph_8cpp_source.html), but I can't find any examples.

I already tried using python bindings for this, but they seem to be lacking some important functions.

Can anyone provide a minimal example of using current clang's API for this task?

Answer (score 2):

For C++ (For C just use clang)

```
clang++ -Xclang -analyze -Xclang -analyzer-checker=debug.ViewCallGraph <file to analyze>
```

This will get you images.